# Sous vide timings for different cuts of steak?

Tags: sous-vide, steak, timing

There are lots of generic guides out there for cooking steak sous vide to different levels of "doneness", but are there any that calculate the timings based on the actual cut of meat? This is particularly relevant as US cuts of meat differ considerably from British ones, and I assume each would require slightly different cooking times (e.g. rump, topside and silverside versus round). See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cuts_of_beef for the classifications.

My intention is to cook four rump steaks simultaneously, two well done (I know, but guests) and two medium rare. Apparently I might run the risk of the fat turning gelatinous on the well done rump steak if it is left in the bath too long. The goal here is to get juicy and tender meat as much as possible irrespective of doneness.

Using generic timings and temperature, I was going to cook the well done steaks for 2 hours at 70C, lowering the temperature to 56C and cooking the medium rare steaks for 2 hours, keeping the well done steaks in the bath for a total of 4 hours, two at 70C and then two at 56C. All steaks will be browned in a very hot grill press (more for the grill marks than anything else), the juices from the sous vide bags being used to create a pan sauce. If need be I can cook the steaks the night before and reheat if this would be a better method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collagen should break down and proteins denature at the same time and temperature no matter what muscle it came from.

Of course, the size of the cut is going to affect how the heat makes it into the meat, which is why Baldwin’s guide focuses more on the size and shape of the meat to achieve a specific doneness

https://douglasbaldwin.com/sous-vide.html#Beef

He does call out a few cuts and how far to cook them, but it’s more about level of doneness with level being a second order thing.